# String into a matrix of strings with javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix

How can I convert string into a matrix of strings in javascript?
This string:

```
str = "[[52827397, 09/02/2021 01:57, Carl], [93575415, 09/02/2021 01:58, Kevin], [45805703, 10/02/2021 01:41, Brian]]";
```

must become like this (programmatically):

```
var str = "[["52827397", "09/02/2021 01:57", "Carl"], ["93575415", "09/02/2021 01:58", "Kevin"], ["45805703", "10/02/2021 01:41", "Brian"]]";
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you have access to whatever is producing your original string, it would make more sense to turn that into the correct format (ie: a valid JSON format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     str = "[[52827397, 09/02/2021 01:57, Carl], [93575415, 09/02/2021 01:58, Kevin], 
     [45805703, 10/02/2021 01:41, Brian]]";

     str=str.replaceAll('[','');
     str=str.replaceAll(']','');
     str=str.split(',');
     let str1=[];
     for(let i=0;i<str.length;i=i+3){
       let a=[str[i+0] , str[i+1]  ,str[i+2] ];
       str1.push(a);
     }
     console.log(str1);
```

I guess this might help you
You can shorten the code for sure i just did it to help